# Query additional API Endpoint with Axios & Vue after getting results from a different endpoint

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-5.6

I'm utilising the following API for a World Cup Laravel app - http://api.football-data.org/docs/v1/index.html#_fixture

This information brings me back today's fixture's as I'm using this code (`config` just holds my API key):

```
const todaysMatches = new Vue({
    el: '#todaysMatches',
    data: {
        todaysMatches: [],
        flags: []
    },
    methods: {
        loadData: function () {
            axios.get("http://api.football-data.org/v1/competitions/467/fixtures/?timeFrame=p1", config)
            .then(response => {this.todaysMatches = response.data});
        }
    },
    mounted: function () {
        this.loadData();
    }
});
```

This brings back the following data sctructure:

[image: response after first call]

Inside each fixture you get an array of `_links` which you can see in the below screenshot:

[image: _links array in response]

Now, what I would like to do is query both the awayTeam api and the homeTeam api because they each have an endpoint of `crestUrl` which returns the country's flag.

You can see that inside my `data` I've set an array prop called `flags` so I was thinking of running additional calls inside my `loadData` method and populate that array for each fixture, but I don't think that's a clean way of doing it.

Can anyone suggest the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used async/await pattern to achieve your requirement as below:

```
loadData: async function() {
  const response = await axios.get(
    "http://api.football-data.org/v1/competitions/467/fixtures/?timeFrame=p1",
    config
  );

  this.todaysMatches = response.data;

  let arr = this.todaysMatches.fixtures.map(fixture => {
    const _links = fixture._links;
    return [
      axios.get(_links.awayTeam.href, config),
      axios.get(_links.homeTeam.href, config)
    ];
  });

  arr.forEach(async item => {
    const away = await item[0];
    const home = await item[1];
    this.flags.push({
      awayFlag: away.data.crestUrl,
      homeFlag: home.data.crestUrl
    });
  });
}
```

Explaination:

- After fetching `todaysMatches` a new array `arr` is created which consists of promises returned by get request to the team's url `[[getAwayTeamInfo, getHomeTeamInfo], [getAwayTeamInfo, getHomeTeamInfo], [getAwayTeamInfo, getHomeTeamInfo],...]`
- We loop through this and await on the promise to get the `crestUrl`
- This `crestUrl` is pushed into `flags` array as an object

  ```
  {
    awayFlag: away.data.crestUrl,
    homeFlag: home.data.crestUrl
  }
  ```

## Update

Adding the flag urls directly to the `this.todaysMatches.fixtures` array

```
loadData: async function() {
  const response = await axios.get(
    "http://api.football-data.org/v1/competitions/467/fixtures/?timeFrame=p1",
    config
  );

  this.todaysMatches = response.data;
  const fixtures = this.todaysMatches.fixtures;

  let arr = fixtures.map(fixture => {
    const _links = fixture._links;
    return [
      axios.get(_links.awayTeam.href, config),
      axios.get(_links.homeTeam.href, config)
    ];
  });

  arr.forEach(async (item, index) => {
    const away = await item[0];
    const home = await item[1];
    this.$set(fixtures, index, {
      ...fixtures[index],
      awayFlag: away.data.crestUrl,
      homeFlag: home.data.crestUrl
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll give this a go now :)

Comment: Is there also a way I could put the flag data inside the `todaysMatches` array rather than the `flags` array so that the flags are directly accessible? I've just realised this would be a better implementation

Comment: Thank you @Vamsi Krishna :)

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much. What does `...fixtures[index]` do?

Comment: It is known as [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). It spreads out the properties of the original object i.e `fixture` and is used to add extra pfoperties which are the flag urls

Comment: Thank you Vamsi, very helpful